# How to group more than one line of text with the datacap?

Tags: ibm-datacap

I have this document and i want to capture more than one line.I'm only managing to capture just one.
I am interested in getting all the content in blue.

Image from my script -

[image: Image from my script]

Result I want to get -

[image: Result I want to get]

Answer (score 0):

Using at least datacap 9.1.1 i think you would maybe want something like:

```
RegExFind_InBlock("objectivo")
GoNextWord("1")
SelectParentBlock()
UpdateFieldWithBlock()
```

Depending on how your recognize action works, you may need to use SelectParentBlock() a few times

Comment: I tried this solution but the text was not found. Need to change something elsewhere?